# Enable multi-currency support on a custom WooCommerce product builder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

With Woocommerce, I use a visual product builder that allow my client to build their own products and I need multi-currency support. The problem is that I can't use multi-currency plugin, because the visual builder doesn't support it.

My question is: How to modify the price of the cart for other currency?

I need for example to modify final cart price like this:

- 10€ > 15$
- 20€ > 20$

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can't use a plugin, then you need to write some code.  I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this free version of the plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-multi-currency/

instead of writing from scratch and make further changes as required to this plugin.

Hope this helps.